# Quiero que el usuario solo pueda elegir una u otra ImageView, no ambas (dos ImageView like dislike)

Tags: java, android, android-imageview

Cómo puedo hacer que solo se pueda seleccionar un `ImageView` no ambos. Tengo dos `ImageViews`, uno representa el botón **like** y el otro el botón **dislike**. El usuario solo puede elegir uno no ambos para un post obviamente. El código no me está dando el resultado esperado. Espero que alguien me pueda señalar lo que estoy haciendo mal.

**CommentAdapter**

```
private ImageView img1, img2;

img1 = view.findViewById(R.id.icon_thumb_up_black);
img2 = view.findViewById(R.id.icon_thumb_down_black);



holder.commentLike.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if (img1.isSelected()) {
                img1.setSelected(false);
            } else {
                img1.setSelected(true);
                img2.setSelected(false);
            }
            if (holder.commentLike.getTag().equals("like")) {
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Comment Liked or Disliked").child(comment.getCommentid()).child("Likes").child(mFirebaseUser.getUid()).setValue(true);
            } else {
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Comment Liked or Disliked").child(comment.getCommentid()).child("Likes").child(mFirebaseUser.getUid()).removeValue();
            }
        });

        holder.commentDislike.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if (img2.isSelected()) {
                img2.setSelected(false);
            } else {
                img1.setSelected(false);
                img2.setSelected(true);
            }
            if (holder.commentDislike.getTag().equals("dislike")) {
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Comment Liked or Disliked").child(comment.getCommentid()).child("Dislikes").child(mFirebaseUser.getUid()).setValue(true);
            } else {
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Comment Liked or Disliked").child(comment.getCommentid()).child("Dislikes").child(mFirebaseUser.getUid()).removeValue();
            }
        });
```

**comment_item**

```
 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon_thumb_up_black"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linear_layout_one"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_thumb_up_black" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon_thumb_up_red"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linear_layout_one"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_thumb_up_red"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon_thumb_down_black"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linear_layout_one"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="35dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/icon_thumb_up_black"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_thumb_down_black" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon_thumb_down_red"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linear_layout_one"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="35dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/icon_thumb_up_black"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_thumb_down_red"
        android:visibility="gone" />
```

```
private void commentLike(final String commentid, final ImageView imageView) {
    if (commentid != null) {
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Comment Liked or Disliked").child(commentid).child("Likes");
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (mFirebaseUser != null)
                    if (dataSnapshot.child(mFirebaseUser.getUid()).exists()) {
                        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_thumb_up_red);
                        imageView.setTag("liked");
                    } else {
                        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_thumb_up_black);
                        imageView.setTag("like");
                    }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}

private void commentDislike(final String commentid, final ImageView imageView) {
    if (commentid != null) {
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Comment Liked or Disliked").child(commentid).child("Dislikes");
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (mFirebaseUser != null)
                    if (dataSnapshot.child(mFirebaseUser.getUid()).exists()) {
                        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_thumb_down_red);
                        imageView.setTag("disliked");
                    } else {
                        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_thumb_down_black);
                        imageView.setTag("dislike");
                    }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Que no funciona, ninguno se selecciona? , img1 es like e img2 es la imagen de dislike?

Comment: @Jorgesys Puedo seleccionar ambos ImageView, pero no tiene que funcionar así. Solo debería poder elegir o uno u otro. Tiene que funcionar exactamente como los botones like y dislike de YouTube en los comentarios. Si le doy un like a un comentario y luego me cambio de opinión y le doy a dislike like tiene que deselegirse automáticamente. Como lo tengo ahora le puedo poner un like y dislike a un post y obviamente no puedes darle un like y un dislike. Tiene que ser o like o dislike, pero no ambos. Sí, img1 like, img2 dislike.

Comment: @Jorgesys acabo de subir ahora el xml file. Para que puedas ver como lo tengo estructurado.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar el mismo listener para determinar los estados, obviamente si uno esta seleccionado el otro debe estar deseleccionado, realiza lo siguiente:

```
holder.commentLike.setOnClickListener(v -> {

            img1.setSelected(true);
            img2.setSelected(false);

            if (holder.commentLike.getTag().equals("like")) {
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Comment Liked or Disliked").child(comment.getCommentid()).child("Likes").child(mFirebaseUser.getUid()).setValue(true);
            } else {
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Comment Liked or Disliked").child(comment.getCommentid()).child("Likes").child(mFirebaseUser.getUid()).removeValue();
            }
        });

        holder.commentDislike.setOnClickListener(v -> {

            img1.setSelected(false);
            img2.setSelected(true);

            if (holder.commentDislike.getTag().equals("dislike")) {
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Comment Liked or Disliked").child(comment.getCommentid()).child("Dislikes").child(mFirebaseUser.getUid()).setValue(true);
            } else {
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Comment Liked or Disliked").child(comment.getCommentid()).child("Dislikes").child(mFirebaseUser.getUid()).removeValue();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Acabo de hacerlo y sigo podiendo elegir ambos... Y cuando los elijo se cambian de color de negro a rojo. Estará el problema e los métodos ```commentLike``` y ```commentDislike``` que tengo? Y en tu respuesta no tendría que hacer algo en plan ```Boolean clickable = false;```